# Wordpress | Page indexing Page is not indexed: Redirect error

Tags: wordpress, indexing, google-search-console

I couldn't indexing for my website. Test live url is success. I am using Wordpress. What is the wrong in this page? Also, i activated Yoast SEO plugin.

[Google search console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61WbV.png)

[Read settings in wp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqaHk.png)

I expect to indexing for Google. Can you help me?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)